# Get text file using FTP each 10 seconds

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am looking for batch file that can get a text file using FTP and run forever with delay 10 seconds.

This is my code:

```
:loop

ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open Server_IPADDRESS
userName
Password
get test.txt
close

TIMEOUT 10
goto loop
```

I keep getting the error

```
ftp> TIMEOUT 10
Invalid command.
ftp> goto loop
Invalid command.
```

What I want is to quit the `ftp` and return to normal `cmd`, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you understand what the `-s:"%~f0"` does.

It tells the `ftp.exe` to run the batch file itself, as if it where an FTP script.

When the `ftp.exe` runs the batch file, it:

- gives you two *"Invalid command"* errors for the `:loop` and `ftp.exe` lines.
- runs the actual FTP script
- gives you two *"Invalid command"* errors for the `TIMEOUT 10` and `goto loop` commands.

On the other hand, the batch file interpreter (the `cmd.exe`) sees the `GOTO:EOF`, what effectively tells it to stop interpreting the batch file. Hence the `TIMEOUT 10` and `goto loop` are never executed.

---

You need to:

- change the `GOTO:EOF` to jump just before the `TIMEOUT 10` command;
- tell the `ftp.exe` to stop after the `close` using `bye` command, to spare you from the latter set of *"Invalid command"* errors.

```
:loop

ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:afterftp
open Server_IPADDRESS
userName
Password
get test.txt
close
bye

:afterftp
TIMEOUT 10
goto loop
```

---

Though way more robust is to separate the FTP script and batch file:

FTP script (`ftp.txt`):

```
open Server_IPADDRESS
userName
Password
get test.txt
close
```

Batch file:

```
:loop

ftp -i -s:ftp.txt

TIMEOUT 10
goto loop
```

---

Or use a temporary file for the FTP script:

```
:loop

echo open Server_IPADDRESS> ftp.txt
echo userName>> ftp.txt
echo Password>> ftp.txt
echo get test.txt>> ftp.txt
echo close>> ftp.txt

ftp -i -s:ftp.txt

del ftp.txt

TIMEOUT 10
goto loop
```

(actually, no need to re-create the `ftp.txt` in every loop)